# Span error when sending email from android device within the app

Tags: android, email, html

I'm working on a simple android app which will display the longitude and lattitude and the phone number and date in text views then sends these parameters through email.

I'm using `JSEE Provider` as email wrapper to send the mail from within the app.when used from the emulator it works like a charm but when i test it on my device I get a **"`SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE` spans cannot have a zero length"** log in my log cat, the app wont crash but the email wont get sent.

I tried sending the values without even using textviews Im still having the same error. Any help please?
Here is my email sending code which i used [JavaMail API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a/2033124#2033124)

Comment: Not really because I'm not using an alternative keyboard and I even tried without the text views nor do i have a contentDescription..but I am using a Samsung device!